# Python Dataframe Filtering with Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

My input dataframe;

```
Stock  PO      Order_test  Order
50     50      10          0
50     20      10          7
10     5       3           3
100    80      5           4
```

I want to filter the with this code;

> a= df[(df['Stock'] - df['PO'])>(df['Order_Test']) &
>   (df['Order_Test'])>(df['Order'])]

But i got this;

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Desired output is;

```
   Stock  PO      Order_test  Order
   50     20      10          7
   100    80      5           4
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, only remove some `()` for enclose both conditions:

```
df = df[(df['Stock'] - df['PO']>df['Order_test']) & (df['Order_test']>df['Order'])]
        ^                                       ^   ^                            ^
      start                                    end start                        end   

print (df)
   Stock  PO  Order_test  Order
1     50  20          10      7
3    100  80           5      4
```